# Formatting Dates in R (Non-standard format)

Tags: r, timezone, strptime

Not new to R or formatting dates in R and wouldn't be asking this question but I am having seriously strange behavior and in the last 2 hours am no closer to resolving it.

I have a dataset which I have imported and want to format the date/time column using `as.POSIXct`. The date is a non-standard format and I've applied what I know to be the proper formatting. Here is a small part of the data that I am having trouble with. Code just after. Problem is that there are 4 NA's starting at `"2015-03-08 02:00:00 PST"`. What gives? This seems completely random as it happens no where else in any of the other 55K observations.

```
bad.Dates<-c("3/7/2015 14:15", "3/7/2015 14:30", "3/7/2015 14:45", "3/7/2015 15:00", 
         "3/7/2015 15:15", "3/7/2015 15:30", "3/7/2015 15:45", "3/7/2015 16:00", 
         "3/7/2015 16:15", "3/7/2015 16:30", "3/7/2015 16:45", "3/7/2015 17:00", 
         "3/7/2015 17:15", "3/7/2015 17:30", "3/7/2015 17:45", "3/7/2015 18:00", 
         "3/7/2015 18:15", "3/7/2015 18:30", "3/7/2015 18:45", "3/7/2015 19:00", 
         "3/7/2015 19:15", "3/7/2015 19:30", "3/7/2015 19:45", "3/7/2015 20:00", 
         "3/7/2015 20:15", "3/7/2015 20:30", "3/7/2015 20:45", "3/7/2015 21:00", 
         "3/7/2015 21:15", "3/7/2015 21:30", "3/7/2015 21:45", "3/7/2015 22:00", 
         "3/7/2015 22:15", "3/7/2015 22:30", "3/7/2015 22:45", "3/7/2015 23:00", 
         "3/7/2015 23:15", "3/7/2015 23:30", "3/7/2015 23:45", "3/8/2015 0:00", 
         "3/8/2015 0:15", "3/8/2015 0:30", "3/8/2015 0:45", "3/8/2015 1:00", 
         "3/8/2015 1:15", "3/8/2015 1:30", "3/8/2015 1:45", "3/8/2015 2:00", 
         "3/8/2015 2:15", "3/8/2015 2:30", "3/8/2015 2:45", "3/8/2015 3:00", 
         "3/8/2015 3:15", "3/8/2015 3:30", "3/8/2015 3:45", "3/8/2015 4:00", 
         "3/8/2015 4:15", "3/8/2015 4:30", "3/8/2015 4:45", "3/8/2015 5:00", 
         "3/8/2015 5:15", "3/8/2015 5:30", "3/8/2015 5:45", "3/8/2015 6:00", 
         "3/8/2015 6:15", "3/8/2015 6:30", "3/8/2015 6:45", "3/8/2015 7:00", 
         "3/8/2015 7:15", "3/8/2015 7:30", "3/8/2015 7:45", "3/8/2015 8:00", 
         "3/8/2015 8:15", "3/8/2015 8:30", "3/8/2015 8:45", "3/8/2015 9:00", 
         "3/8/2015 9:15", "3/8/2015 9:30", "3/8/2015 9:45", "3/8/2015 10:00", 
         "3/8/2015 10:15", "3/8/2015 10:30", "3/8/2015 10:45", "3/8/2015 11:00", 
         "3/8/2015 11:15", "3/8/2015 11:30", "3/8/2015 11:45", "3/8/2015 12:00", 
         "3/8/2015 12:15", "3/8/2015 12:30", "3/8/2015 12:45", "3/8/2015 13:00", 
         "3/8/2015 13:15", "3/8/2015 13:30", "3/8/2015 13:45", "3/8/2015 14:00", 
         "3/8/2015 14:15", "3/8/2015 14:30", "3/8/2015 14:45", "3/8/2015 15:00", 
         "3/8/2015 15:15") 

as.POSIXct(strptime(bad.Dates,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
```

Comment: That's the exact time that daylight savings time (PDT) began.  So that hour is essentially missing in time.  Spooky!

Comment: Nice catch, @RichardScriven. Curtis, stop fighting time :)

Comment: Wow! Mine blown. Lol Supposed I should have noticed as it says `"2015-03-08 01:45:00 PST"` before and `"2015-03-08 03:00:00 PDT"` after the NA's.

Comment: Never mess with time-stamps after lunch.

Comment: It's generally good form to use "UTC" or "GMT" as a timezone when importing time/date data unless you explicitly want the timezone and daylight savings to be considered.

Comment: BTW. Solved my issue by specifying `tz` in as.POSIXct()`. Now it reports everything in the same timezone without NA's. Thank you for your help. @RichardScriven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this example reproducible/solvable regardless of location, specify the timezones via `tz=` explicitly:

```
bad.Dates <- c("3/8/2015 1:45", "3/8/2015 2:00", "3/8/2015 2:15",
               "3/8/2015 2:30", "3/8/2015 2:45", "3/8/2015 3:00")
as.POSIXct(bad.Dates, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="US/Pacific")

#[1] "2015-03-08 01:45:00 PST"
#[2] NA                       
#[3] NA                       
#[4] NA                       
#[5] NA                       
#[6] "2015-03-08 03:00:00 PDT"
```

You get `NA`s because those times don't exist in the modern-day timekeeping of the US Pacific region.

> Most of the United States, Canada, and Mexico's northern border cities
>   will begin Daylight Saving Time (DST) on Sunday, March 8, 2015. People
>   in areas that observe DST will spring forward one hour from 2am
>   (02:00) to 3am (03:00), local time.
>   *Source:* http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/usa-canada-start-dst-2015.html

Specifying a timezone like `"UTC"` that doesn't observe daylight savings will get around this issue.

```
as.POSIXct(bad.Dates, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")
#[1] "2015-03-08 01:45:00 UTC"
#[2] "2015-03-08 02:00:00 UTC"
#[3] "2015-03-08 02:15:00 UTC"
#[4] "2015-03-08 02:30:00 UTC"
#[5] "2015-03-08 02:45:00 UTC"
#[6] "2015-03-08 03:00:00 UTC"
```